# WordPress: limit login attempts (without plugins)

Tags: php, wordpress, security, authentication, nginx

I'm looking for a way to limit the attempts an user can make to login. I saw [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/) plugin but it hasn't been updated in over 2 years.. and if available I always prefer a way that doesn't involve plugins. :)

Is there a variable that can be set in `wp-config.php`?

Otherwise, is there a way to achive this via webserver config? I have nginx 1.7.4.

Comment: Have you seen [http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Plugins)?

Comment: I still use Limit Login Attempts as an MU Plugin and it works great for me.

Answer (score 5):

I founded this class.

```
<?php
/**
* CLASS LIMIT LOGIN ATTEMPTS
* Prevent Mass WordPress Login Attacks by setting locking the system when login fail.
* To be added in functions.php or as an external file.
*/
if ( ! class_exists( 'Limit_Login_Attempts' ) ) {
class Limit_Login_Attempts {
    var $failed_login_limit = 3;                    //Giris Denemesi
    var $lockout_duration   = 1800;                 //Sureyi sn cinsinden giriniz. 30 dakika: 60*30 = 1800
    var $transient_name     = 'attempted_login';    //Transient used

    public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'authenticate', array( $this, 'check_attempted_login' ), 30, 3 );
    add_action( 'wp_login_failed', array( $this, 'login_failed' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    /**
    * Lock login attempts of failed login limit is reached
    */
    public function check_attempted_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
        if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
            $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );
            if ( $datas['tried'] >= $this->failed_login_limit ) {
                $until = get_option( '_transient_timeout_' . $this->transient_name );
                $time = $this->when( $until );
                //Display error message to the user when limit is reached
                return new WP_Error( 'too_many_tried', sprintf( __( '<strong>HATA</strong>: Kimlik dogrulama sinirina ulastiniz, %1$s sonra lutfen tekrar deneyiniz.' ) , $time ) );
            }
        }
        return $user;
    }

    /**
    * Add transient
    */
    public function login_failed( $username ) {
        if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
            $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );
            $datas['tried']++;
        if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit )
            set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
        } else {
            $datas = array(
            'tried'     => 1
        );
            set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Return difference between 2 given dates
    * @param  int      $time   Date as Unix timestamp
    * @return string           Return string
    */
    private function when( $time ) {
        if ( ! $time )
        return;
            $right_now = time();
            $diff = abs( $right_now - $time );
            $second = 1;
            $minute = $second * 60;
            $hour = $minute * 60;
            $day = $hour * 24;
        if ( $diff < $minute )
            return floor( $diff / $second ) . ' saniye';
        if ( $diff < $minute * 2 )
            return "yaklasik 1 dakika once";
        if ( $diff < $hour )
            return floor( $diff / $minute ) . ' dakika';
        if ( $diff < $hour * 2 )
            return 'yaklasik  1 saat once';
            return floor( $diff / $hour ) . ' saat';
    }
}
}
//Enable it:
new Limit_Login_Attempts();
```

Answer (score 4):

Altough the post is quite old I will provide my findings because I couldn't find the answer myself until today. 
Looked in the codex and whatnot, but everywhere I got ordered to use a plugin - which I do not want.

So to answer your question:

> Is there a variable that can be set in wp-config.php?

No, there is not a variable you can set in wp-config.

> Otherwise, is there a way to achive this via webserver config? I have nginx 1.7.4.

I am no webserver magician but I guess not.

But! - From this [blog post by Etienne Tremel](https://coderwall.com/p/dc2bbg/limit-login-attemps) I got that there is a filter:

`add_filter( 'authenticate', (...)`

and function hook:

`add_action( 'wp_login_failed', (...)`

you can use to tap into the login-process. With that information I was able to anticipate on login-attempts with my own custom code.

In his blog-article you'll find a copy paste piece of code to dump in your functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start would be downloading and looking under the hood of a plugin that already does this. Studying what methods can be employed will help you in your implementation regardless if the plugin is up to date or not.

Comment: Not sure why people keep missing the without plugins part in the question.

Comment: Study a plugin and learn the "method". Is there a method that sets a variable? This is something that can easily be learned by examining what's already out there. That will assist the OP can find a way to implement this without a plugin.

Comment: Writing your own plugin our using another makes little difference. In fact a third party plugin is then preferable. Using the principles but modifying a core file becomes hard to maintain.

Comment: That is questionable. It really depends on ones programming skills and knowledge of the wordpress plugin architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting this kind of functionality is indeed best done outside this application and even it's programming language.

Denying connections is typically the task of a firewall and this also protects the webserver.

Put these two together you quickly arrive at fail2ban or sshguard. A hosting company I work with has done exactly that, so I know it's possible to do that. They use a four strikes and you're out policy. I'm not sure if their code is public, but it shouldn't be to hard to come up with a recipe, both have excellent documentation.